# How does "seem" work?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I found these sentences:

```
1. Tony always seems to offend people.
2. The old man seems to have mistaken us for some people he knew years ago.
3. They seem to be taking a long time to decide.
```

Can we rephrase them this way?

```
1. It always seems Tony offends people.
2. It seems the old man mistook us for some people he had known years ago.
3.1. It seems they take a long time to decide.
3.2. It seems they are taking a long time to decide.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can also use *seems that* but is deemed redundant so you can omit.

Comment: I wonder which rephrased sentence is correct: 3.1 or 3.2.

Comment: 3.1 needs to be in the present continuous.  .........that they are taking a long time.............

Comment: But I don't quite understand 3.2. Does it mean "it seems they have been deciding for a long time" or "it seems they are going to take a long time to decide?

Comment: It means the opinion of the speaker (or writer) is that they have been taking a long time to arrive at a decision.  There is still no decision finalised.

Comment: Is "they seem to have been taking a long time to decide" correct sentence?

Comment: Yes, it is present perfect continuous.  A continuous event that started in the past and is still in progress now.

Comment: *"It seems they take a long time to decide."* This means that they *customarily* take a long time to make decisions.